# How to retrieve value of text field inside while loop with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

Inside the while loop there are text boxes. There is JavaScript function called checkNum() which is use to retrieve the text box value but i don't get it how to do that?

```js
<script>
function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
       }
    
function checkNum()
{
 var num = document.getElementById('num');
 
}
</script>
```

```html
<table width="506" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="189" align="center">Text One</td>
    
  </tr>
  <?php
  $i =0;
  $data = "select * from tbl_person";
  $query = mysqli_query($conn,$data);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
   $i++;
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="num<?php echo $i;?>" id="num<?php echo $i;?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/></td>
    
  </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  
</table>
```

Comment: first, realise that php creates a whole page and sends it to the browser ... if you look at the source of the page on the browser, perhaps you'll get a better idea of what you need to do ... and ask

Comment: How are you attempting to call that function? What event are you attaching it to?

Comment: after creating the page suppose there are five textbox after the loop complited and then i enterd some data now i want that data through javascript function is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is, if you explain what you are trying to do properly - again, how are you calling the `checkNum()` function?

Comment: onblur() inside the text box

Comment: I dont see the `onblur` attribute in the html, do you mean a different text box? The answer is going to be simple when i work out what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
    function loopTexts(numRows)
    {
      for(var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++)
      {
        var txt = document.getElementById('txt'+i);
        var str = txt.value;
        alert(str);
      }
    }


<?php
//Some query here
    $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($resultSet);
//Loop through the result set and create the fields as you did
?>

    <input type="text" value="text1" id="txt1"/>
    <input type="text" value="text2" id="txt2"/>
    <input type="text" value="text3" id="txt3"/>
    <input type="text" value="text4" id="txt4"/>
    <input type="text" value="text5" id="txt5"/>
//echo the parameter $numRows to pass it to the JS function
    <input type="button" value="Loop!" onclick=<?php echo "loopTexts($numRows);"; ?>/>
```

If you don't know how many text boxes will be created during runtime, pass it as an argument to the javascript function and use it in the `for` loop.

Call the function in whatever event you are supposed to use it.

Comment: yes its right but what if the text box count depends upon database record

Comment: Assuming you are using PHP and MySQL, get the number of rows returned from the query with mysql_num_rows. Pass this value to the Javascript function (loopTexts($numRows) and use this parameter in for loop.

Comment: yes you are right but actually i want t validate those field

Answer (score 0):

Have the function accept the input as a parameter:

```
function checkNum(input)
{
    var num = input.value;

}
```

Then add the onblur attribute to the field, and pass `this` as a parameter:

```
<input type="text" onblur="checkNum(this)" name="num<?php echo $i;?>" id="num<?php echo $i;?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>
```